# How to make an ng-click event conditional?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this code inside ng-repeat:

```
<a href="#" class="disabled" ng-click="doSomething(object)">Do something</a>
```

**How to make a condition that the button is disabled when it has `class="disabled"`?**

Or is there a way to do it in Javascript so that will look like:

```
$('.do-something-button').click(function(){
  if (!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
    do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score 208, accepted):

It is not good to manipulate with DOM (including checking of attributes) in any place except directives. You can add into scope some value indicating if link should be disabled.

But other problem is that ngDisabled does not work on anything except form controls, so you can't use it with <a>, but you can use it with <button> and style it as link.

Another way is to use lazy evaluation of expressions like `isDisabled || action()` so action wouold not be called if `isDisabled` is true.

Here goes both solutions: http://plnkr.co/edit/5d5R5KfD4PCE8vS3OSSx?p=preview

Comment: so to conclude: ng-click="isDisabled || action()" did the trick

Comment: better: `||` should be `&&`, although it works in your plunk, if isDisabled is a method double pipes keep on checking for a valid expression. This is not the case with `&&`

Comment: @polyclick the logic would then change too. if the isDisabled returns true, then the action() would get called.

Comment: @polyclick: But the point is to __not__ continue checking if disabled. Plus, in your version, if `isDisabled()` returns false, neither will `action()` be called, nor does checking "for a valid expression" continue.

Comment: @UCJava, if && is used, it will be !isDisabled (or isEnabled) then. It's either ng-click="Form.$valid && action()" or ng-click="Form.$invalid || action()"

Answer (score 47):

We can add ng-click event conditionally without using disabled class.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="object in objects">
<span ng-click="!object.status && disableIt(object)">{{object.value}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

I use the && expression which works perfectly for me.

For example,

```
<button ng-model="vm.slideOneValid" ng-disabled="!vm.slideOneValid" ng-click="vm.slideOneValid && vm.nextSlide()" class="btn btn-light-green btn-medium pull-right">Next</button>
```

If `vm.slideOneValid` is false, the second part of the expression is not fired. I know this is putting logic into the DOM, but it's a quick a dirty way to get ng-disabled and ng-click to place nice.

Just remember to add ng-model to the element to make ng-disabled work.

Answer (score 7):

Basically `ng-click` first checks the `isDisabled` and based on its value it will decide whether the function should be called or not.

```
<span ng-click="(isDisabled) || clicked()">Do something</span>
```

OR read it as

```
<span ng-click="(if this value is true function clicked won't be called. and if it's false the clicked will be called) || clicked()">Do something</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `ng-class`.
Here is my simple example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/wS3QkQ5dvHNdc6Lb8ZSF?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="object in objects">
  <span ng-class="{'disabled': object.status}" ng-click="disableIt(object)">
    {{object.value}}
  </span>
</div>
```

The status is a custom attribute of object, you could name it whatever you want.
The `disabled` in `ng-class` is a CSS class name, the `object.status` should be `true` or `false`

You could change **every object's status** in function `disableIt`.
In your Controller, you could do this:

```
$scope.disableIt = function(obj) {
  obj.status = !obj.status
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue also and I simply found out that if you simply remove the "#" the issue goes off. Like this :

```
<a href="" class="disabled" ng-click="doSomething(object)">Do something</a>
```

Comment: `href` should not be used, use `ng-href` instead.

Comment: @Felipe Alarcon `ng-href` is only necessary when you need to calculate the path dynamically. If the path never changes, `href` is fine.