# Disable ng-click on HTML DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an `<a>` element which has `ng-click` attribute. 
On certain conditions, I want to disable `ng-click` on this element. I'm using jquery to find this element and I'm trying to stop click by every possible way. For example : `return false ;` `event.stopPropagation()` and etc. Also, I remove `ng-click` attribute with

```
$(element).removeAttr('ng-click');
```

,but event still firing. Is it possible to stop (disable) `ng-click` by jquery ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unbind ng-click dynamically from element : angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754141/unbind-ng-click-dynamically-from-element-angularjs)

Comment: What about adding a condition in your `ng-click` function back in the controller?

Comment: Why not add `ng-disabled` which evaluates to your condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was so close.. find a solution ..

```
var temp = $(result.element).removeAttr('ng-click');
$(result.element).replaceWith(temp);
```

I just need to replace old element with new one but before that , must remove attribute and then it's working.

Comment: What condition do you what to remove the `ng-click`? If you add bit more details to the question, someone might able to help you get a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

### First Option

You can always add `disabled` attribute on the anchor element to prevent `ng-click` from triggering. You also need to use CSS when adding disabled attribute. See the working example below

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("FooController", function($scope) {

  $scope.sayHello = function() {
    alert("Hello!!");
  };
});
```

```css
a[disabled] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="FooController">

  <a href="" disabled ng-click="sayHello()">Say Hello</a>
</div>
```

### Second option

You can make use of a directive to remove `ng-click`. But that will not work with jQuery i.e. if you add this directive using jQuery, it won't work.

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("FooController", function($scope) {

  $scope.sayHello = function() {
    alert("Hello!!");
  };
});

app.directive("disableclick", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 1000,    // setting higher priority to let this directive execute before ngClick
    compile: function(element, attr) {
      attr.ngClick = null;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="FooController">

  <a href="" disableclick ng-click="sayHello()">Say Hello</a>
</div>
```

Comment: No ,this not working. This was the first thing that i've tried

Comment: Why do you want to use jQuery for this. I've a better option directly with Angular

Comment: Because i can't in this case , it's very complicated and i must do so many refactoring .. but yes , you're right , the best solution to do this is by Angular ..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it the Angular way you should use ng-disabled on the element like:

```
<a ng-click="someClickHandler()" ng-disabled="isDisabled">Link</a>
```

Replacing elements in the DOM is a very bad idea unless you know what you are doing. If there are any bindings the element need to be compiled first.

If this doesn't work try to replace a element with button.