# AngularJS: Add conditional add ng-onclick?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if, angular-ng

I'm working on a directive so I can reuse the same layout and piece of code but there are some small variations for the different use cases.

On of these variations I want to deal with by allowing some settings to the directive where I can set a `{"clickable":"true","fn":"clickMe"}`

But in my layout of the directive, how do I set it so if the options `clickable` is set to true it will add the angular attribute directive `ng-onlick=clickMe()` and if it's not, then just don't add the attribute at all.

I tried to use the AngularJS directive `ng-attr` `ng-attr-ng-click="{{options.fn||undefined}}"` but it raises an error when using `{{ }}` and doesn't work when not using them either.

Can I put this into some conditional logic with angular besides making the entire html element twice with in ng-if ???

`<span class="list-item" ng-attr-ng-click="{{options.fn||undefined}}">My list item</span>`

Please let me know if my question is unclear and I'll try to elaborate.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786492/if-statement-in-ng-click

Comment: Thanks Ujjwal, that actually helped a lot.. I've really been searching for an existing answer for my question with no luck so fantastic you posted it to me :-)

Comment: Glad , it worked out for you :)

Comment: Another way is to simply add a class which adds the css property `pointer-events:none;`. This way you could disable the cursor pointer etc for a more self explanatory UI