# Using one ng-click to call the different functions in different condition angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two functions:

1. function: keyword search
2. function: sentence search

There is a box list which contains the options: keyword, sentence

I need to use only one button: only one ng-click but call the two functions according to the box list selection.

```
ng-click ="{if xxx, keywordsearch(); else:sentencesearch()}"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786492/if-statement-in-ng-click  please check this one

Comment: refer this link : https://php.quicoto.com/inline-ifelse-statement-ngclick-angularjs/
`ng-click="variable = (condition=='X' ? 'Y' : 'X')"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this ways:

```
<select ng-model="bSelection">
    <option value="fnOne">One</option>
    <option value="fnTwo">Two</option>
</select>

<button ng-click="bSelection == 'fnOne' ? fnOne2() : fnTwo2()">Click</button>
```

Comment: may i know what is fnOne2() : fnTwo2()??

Comment: these are function which you want to call on basis of selection.