# Dynamically disable all ng-clicks within an element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a directive `disable-ng-clicks` and under certain conditions, I want to prevent all ng-clicks that are children of the directive. Here is some example markup:

```
<div disable-ng-clicks> <!-- directive -->
  <a ng-click="someAction()"></a>
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <a ng-click="anotherAction()"></a>
    <a ng-click="moreActions()"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If these were normal hyperlinks, I could do something like this in the `link` function:

```
function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
  var ngClicks = angular.element(iElement[0].querySelectorAll('[ng-click]'));
  ngClicks.on('click', function(event) {
    if(trigger) { // a dynamic variable that triggers disabling the clicks
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
}
```

But this does not work for `ng-click` directives. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Well the element that you are clicking isn't the div, is the anchor. You should put this in every anchor or change the directive to disable ng-click for child elements. The way you are doing It will work only for the element that has the directive.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I can attach the click handler onto the parent and it it executes when I click on a child.

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but you will need to change the directive to look for every chield from the element that has It.

Comment: Ahh I see what you are saying. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best I could come up with. I created a new directive to replace ng-click:

```
 directive('myClick', ['$parse', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function($element, attrs) {
      var fn = $parse(attrs.myClick);
      return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var disabled = false;
        scope.$on('disableClickEvents', function () {
          disabled = true;
        });
        scope.$on('enableClickEvents', function () {
          disabled = false;
        });
        element.on('click', function (event) {
          if (!disabled) {
            scope.$apply(function () {
              fn(scope, { $event: event });
            });
          }
        });
      };
    }
  }
}]);
```

So in a different directive, I can have:

```
if (condition) { 
  scope.$broadcast('disableClickEvents');
}
```

and when I want to re-enable:

```
if (otherCondition) { 
  scope.$broadcast('enableClickEvents');
}
```

I don't like having to use a different directive for ng-click, but this is the best plan I could think of.

Comment: I'm just going to mark this as the answer since it satisfies my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You are catching 'click' event on parent only because of [JS events bubbling](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing), so if you want to intercept it on all descendants, so your directive should get all descendants of current element, listen their 'click' event and prevent it if necessary.

Comment: Can you post example code? I can grab all descendants with ng-click, but even if I try to run `event.preventDefault()`, it occurs too late because Angular's ng-click has already taken over as the click handler.

Comment: An ng-click event is not a default action, which is what event.preventDefault() prevents. Instead, you need to unregister click events -- take a look at my answer for an example directive.

Comment: I updated the question, that was a mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

This directive will iterate over all child elements, check to see if they have an ng-click attribute, and if they do, it will disable any registered click event handlers:

```
directive('disableNgClicks', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
      angular.forEach(elem.children(), function(childElem) {
        if (childElem.outerHTML.indexOf("ng-click") > -1) {
          angular.element(childElem).off('click');
        }
      });
    }
  }
})
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/SVtBBCi3IC44q1Kwdb1Q?p=preview)

Comment: Instead of unregistering the click events, I would rather `stopImmediatePropagation` because I want to toggle this on and off. Unfortunately, I am not able to get my directive to execute its click handler before ng-click. I have found that [priority](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208899/intercepting-ng-click-in-angularjs) dictates order when two directives are on the same element, but when one is the parent, I'm not sure how to control which click handler fires first.

Comment: Yes, it's easy enough to prevent the ng-click event on a per-element basis, but I don't see any obvious way to override their behavior using a parent directive while allowing for disabling. The ordering is a real issue, as you've found. I think that your best bet is to use a scope variable that prevents the ng-click handler from being called when it is set to true: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545744/how-to-make-a-condition-on-ng-click-in-angularjs

Comment: Small comment. The directive has to be restrict: 'A' to work with @thetallweeks code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 2 years ago but I needed to do something similar and came up with a rather simple solution.

The object:

```
items: {
    item1 : {
        selected: 0,
        other: 'stuff'
    },
    item2 : {
        selected : 1,
        other: 'stuff'
    }  
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-model="item.selected" ng-click="selectParent($event)">
    <div ng-click="item.selected ? selectChild($event) : null">Child</div>
</div>
```

The functions:

```
$scope.selectParent = function($event) {
    var itemScope = angular.element($event.currentTarget)scope().item;
    itemScope.selected = !itemScope.selected;
}

$scope.selectChild = function($event) {
    $event.stopPropagation;
    console.log('I only get triggered if parent item is selected');
}
```

This is a pretty raw example of what I did. You should probably be using a directive that gives you $scope rather than angular.element($event.currentTarget).scope... either way the simplistic inline if logic is what I was really getting at. You can call a function or not based on some value.