# UI Blocking in Angular app

Tags: angularjs

I have a `<div>` that slides in from the left when a button is clicked. It is 300px wide and therefore doesn't cover the whole screen. The right hand side of the screen is still "clickable."

Is it possible to render a part of the screen "unclickable" whilst the `<div>` is on show?

Comment: Sounds like you want it to basically be a modal div? http://jsfiddle.net/kumarmuthaliar/GG9Sa/1/

Comment: I would probably build the div element to have a full-width "invisible" div display underneath the left-div, that "eats" clicks. Simpler than saving an "isOpen" variable and conditionally checking all clickable elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the right hand side of the screen is using `ng-click`.

You can do something like this:

```
<div ng-click="LeftButtonClick||DoFunction()">Right Side</div>
```

If LeftButtonClick is true, then the function will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

plz refer [How to make a condition on ng-click in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545744/how-to-make-a-condition-on-ng-click-in-angularjs)

angular doesn't check whether is clickable, so you need to add an expression before it